# Translation of 'nothing'

Tags: vocabulary

What is the most accurate translation of the phrase, 'from nothing, [back] to nothing.'? my own attempt is 'Ex nihilo in nihilum' Does that sound right?

Comment: Heavily related: [Nihil vs. nihilum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2645/1088)

Answer (score 9):

Apart from the choice of prepositions (which will depend on the exact implications you're going for), the main difficulty here is that *nihil* is a "defective" noun: it's missing some of its forms. The ablative is very rare, and the dative doesn't exist at all, as far as I know.

But the phrase *ex nihilō* does very much exist, so that's a good starting point. For the second half, I would use *ad nihil*. The phrase feels like it wants "toward" more than "into", and *ad-nihil-ō* is a verb meaning "to bring to nothing" (the ancestor of "annihilate"). The accusative is one case that definitely exists for *nihil*, so you don't have to worry about that part.

So I would say ***ex nihilō ad nihil***. You can also use *nīl* or *nihilum* for the accusative, if you prefer, but I like the sound of the bare *nihil*. You can also use *in* instead of *ad*, echoing the famous phrase *quia pulvis es et **in** pulverem reverteris*, but I find the meaning of "turn into" less clear without the verb *vertō*, which is why I prefer *ad*.

(You can also add verbs, if you want: "from nothing you come/arise/are created and to nothing you will return". But the choice of verbs depends even more on your intended meaning.)

Comment: Thank you, Draconis, that is a fine and sensitive reply which understands the context of the question.